# How to set numeric value in EditText?

Tags: android

I want to make a simple calculator My code is below:

```
package som.dev.android.calc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CalcApp extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button addValues, subValues, equalsValue;
    EditText inputValue;

    int inputNum = 0;
    public int value1;
    public int value2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // initializing Views
        inputValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        addValues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        subValues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subBtn);
        equalsValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equalsBtn);

        // adding onClick Listeners
        addValues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pressed = true;
                value1 = Integer.parseInt(inputValue.getText().toString());
                inputValue.setText("");
            }
        });

        equalsValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                value2 = Integer.parseInt(inputValue.getText().toString());
                int result = value1+value2;

                inputValue.setText(result);// There an exception occurs....
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it does not sets result to Edittext in my app and an exception occurs and message comes Unfortunately app is colsed some thing like that so please any one tell me the solution of this problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this `inputValue.setText(""+result);`instead of `inputValue.setText(result);// There an exception occurs....`

just conversion integer into string

Answer (score 4):

change Following Line:-

```
inputValue.setText(result);
```

to

```
inputValue.setText(String.Valueof(result));
```

then your error is solved.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get an exception is that the EditText thinks you are setting a resource id. You need to convert the integer to a string yourself Integer.toString(result) before using it in the EditText Object. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html